# Update photo description (message) on Facebook using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to either delete a photo my app u/l to FB or change its description.
It seems deleting a photo is not possible 
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6337969/cant-delete-photo-via-facebook-api

How about updating the photo  description (message) ?

Answer (score 0):

We can delete the photos that are uploaded via our APP. we can use the ID of photo to delete it.